# Suitable SDK to develop quick game?

Tags: 3d

I'm currently undertaking a personal project at home that I need to turn around inside the next few months (which working full time and still learning programming makes it a tad difficult). I'm looking for suggestions on SDK's or tools (preferably free or that come with games, similar to steam tools) that I can use to develop a "game". I'm OK with coding but have no 3D development skills at all.

I've very little experience with mod tools or SDK's at all but I'm hoping someone can point me in the direction of one that does the following:

- A decent library of prefab 3D models to build scenes.
- Ability to add scripting to the scene

I've used Unity before and would prefer to continue to do so however I really have the worst 3D skills imaginable and can't waste time learning them.

I'd be looking for pre-fab items that are both industrial and possibly more lush environments (trees etc). If it makes any difference (due to licencing and what-not) I **WILL NOT** be selling this game or marketing it in any way and I am a University Student if any places do educations licences.

Another alternative would be to source free 3d models elsewhere but again while I'm still learning I have no idea where to look if someone could point me in the right direction I'll do the rest of the digging.

Thanks

Comment: Please have a look to my improved answer. It may help you and others :)

Comment: -1.  According to the [faq](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/faq), "how do I get started", "what SDK to use", and "where to find free assets" are all off-topic for this site.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Open Source Game SDK/frameworks/Engines may help you (for educational purposes and other purposes, for example to develop game quicker)

- http://www.panda3d.org/
- http://www.ogre3d.org/
- http://getmoai.com/moai-sdk.html
- https://github.com/badlogic/libgdx
- http://code.google.com/p/catcake/

Unity has 3D Game Development Student Version - **Unity - Studica**

- http://www.studica.com/unity
- http://www.studica.com/unity/unity-pro-4-student.html

Regarding 3D, Unity is one of the best. You can use the **Free Unity Indie Package**

- http://blogs.unity3d.com/2009/10/29/a-free-unity/
- http://www.rockpapershotgun.com/2009/10/28/unity3d-for-free/

Also others

- http://www.giderosmobile.com/
- http://www.coronalabs.com/

**EDIT :**

For free unity 3d character models, followings may help you

- http://www.turbosquid.com/
- http://www.the3dstudio.com/
- http://www.digimation.com/home/Modelbank.aspx
- http://u3d.as/content/mixamo/zombie-character-pack/1sK
- http://thefree3dmodels.com/

Resources

- http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/41184/where-can-i-download-pre-made-3d-models.html
- http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/23947/free-3d-ready-model.html
- http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/47004/where-can-i-download-models-for-unity3d.html

Comment: Problem is that lacks 3D models yeah? Most of those linked seem exactly like Unity in that you can script and do everything you want, what you can't do though is have a nice library of models at your disposal, which is currently my problem. I'll keep looking online it seems I might have to bite the bullet and do what I can in Unity, I'd be willing to pay for 3d models too I guess if that was a route I could take.

Comment: @gRnt, I have edited my answer as your comment. Please have a look to the Edited Answer.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for SDKs with large model packs? I don't think that happens.

However, you can look at the strongly integrated Unity Asset Store (which does have free items like this [beautiful zombie](http://u3d.as/content/mixamo/zombie-character-pack/1sK)). For XNA, there is [Turbosquid](http://www.turbosquid.com).

And of course there are other sites with collections of free 3D models; you probably could import them into Unity. You can have a look at:

- http://thefree3dmodels.com/
- [Ryzom](http://media.ryzom.com/) - a whole MMORPG gone CC-SA
- [Turbosquid](http://www.turbosquid.com) I mentioned before

Comment: Thanks, I remember back in the day using level editors and such that you could basically pull in any models you wanted and mess around with them but I guess I'm not really going to be able to "scipt" those scenes as much as I am make static environments, which might actually work for the sake of what I want to do but I might persevere with Unity.....I'll mark this for answered for now as it did confirm my suspicions cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you were asking for a little SDK, so I won't list now every Engine/SDK.

The Irrlicht Engine may suitable for you.